# How can I create a backup ROM compatible with ADB sideload?

Tags: adb, rom-flashing, side-loading

Can someone explain how to backup a **rooted** Android device into a ZIP file that would be compatible with `adb sideload`? Is it possible **without having a custom recovery** installed?

Is there a specific name for a ROM in that format? Is the format documented somewhere? Are there tools that package ROMs into that format?

Comment: Adb backup? Why no adb backup?  You can then just adb restore.

Comment: @DanBrown: I didn't realize that 'adb backup' can backup the /system partition... Can it really do that?

Comment: Don't know for sure, actually. Try adb Pull, and then adb push it back if you can't adb backup /system. You really should be using a custom recovery though. Why not?

Comment: Shoot, I forgot: You can use the app ZIPme by Jrummy.

Comment: @DanBrown: Yeah, doing this from recovery would be ideal, but not an option for me. I've got a locked bootloader and no hack for this device yet (YT3-X50), so no way to actually install a custom recovery. I know that apps like FlashFire can create images of all partitions (including system) w/o recovery, but the missing piece is how to create a sideload-compatible jar, once I have the partition images.

Comment: @DanBrown: It's a long story (short version - I messed up :)), but my goal is to take a rooted YT3-X50, lift its ROM, and then use it to resurrect a bricked YT3-X50, which still accepts sideloads, but is otherwise toast, b/c I ruined the /system partition on it.

Comment: Use the ZIPme app, or any of its similar. Should help ye

Comment: Also, for the resurrection bit, do the devices manufacturer(s) have a PC tool-perhaps with a recovery option?

Comment: Did you solve the issue? maybe [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DyUainEJwLM) could help. I don't know if it's sideload compatible though.